# cancel setInterval in componentDidMount on props render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I cancel `setInterval` if `this.props.firebase` is not equal to `null`?

```
VerifyEmail = () => {
  const { firebase } = this.props;
  console.log(firebase);
  if (firebase !== null) {
    this.setState({ validCode: true, verifiedCode: true });
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  const { firebase } = this.props;
  if (firebase === null) {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.VerifyEmail(), 1000);
  } else if (firebase !== null) {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalID);
}
```

Currently, `this.VerifyEmail` is repeated and my attempt to `clearInterval` if `this.props.firebase` is not equal to `null` does not run.

Also, if you have another method that will automatically action `this.VerifyEmail()` on page render and when `this.props.firebase` is not equal to `null`. Please suggest.

Comment: try add console inside "if" and "else" and watch what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)(or `cDM` in short) runs just once when component is mounted. Later when you change `props` provided it is not called. Upon `props` is changed [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is run. You may place your check there keeping in mind to check `prevProps.firebase !== this.props.firebase` or you may stack in endless re-rendering. Just like that

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { firebase: prevFirebase } = this.prevProps;
    const { firebase } = this.props;
    if (!prevFirebase && firebase) { // null => not-null
        this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.VerifyEmail(), 1000);
    }
    if (prevFirebase && !firebase) { // not-null => null
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
    }
}
```

Don't miss placing the same logic in `componentDidMount`(for case when `props.firebase` has been provided initially) and `componentDidUpdate`(for case when `props.firebase` is initially `null` and later is assigned to `props`).

But I believe there could be more DRY solution. Do you really need to render this component until data is retrieved? Do you render some placeholder until `firebase` appears and data is loaded? If yes, then how about lift up data loading to parent component? Then your component would retrieve data through `props` and it might have render as simple as `(this.props.data && ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with `componentDidUpdate` is that it'll repeat on the `setState` within the function unless. Also I don't have another `prop` to compare against. Please correct me if I have that wrong in my thinking.

Comment: `this.props.firebase` is a list of functions that are wrapped and passed to the component via `context` (so technically it is within the parent component. The problem I face is in this component, the `function` mounted on page render has zero user actions. They click a link in email, it loads the page, verifies the parameters and then returns a message before navigating away. Therefore the only way I could think of was to call within `componentDidMount`. And to ensure that the `function` runs I added a setInterval but my attempts to then cancel the setInterval seem to not work.

Comment: is your `setInterval` just to wait until `props.firebase` becomes not-`null`?

Comment: Yes, once it's available, the `function` runs and the `setInterval` should be cancelled.

Comment: with `componentDidUpdate` you don't need running interval then.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the `setInterval` from your answer as suggested and it works how I intended.